# Keeping no data values in clipped rasters

Tags: qgis, clip

I am using QGIS and I have a raster layer with temperature values. The ocean has "no data" values, since I need only terrestrial information. I need to clip this image to retain only one part of the raster... I used the clipper tool, but the resulting clipped raster shows values of "0" in the ocean (instead of the original 'no data' values)... I can't convert 0 to 'no data' since my image contains 0 in the terrestrial portion that I need to keep... 
Is there a way to keep no data values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the raster clipper from QGIS 2.6.0 (Brighton):

[image]

Check the box that says No Data Value and put in a value outside the range for your data that is valid for the pixel type. It is exactly the same in QGIS 2.0.1 (Dufour).